# Where to upload my PHP files on web hosting server?

Tags: web-hosting

I have a GoDaddy web hosting account with a cPanel access. I am trying to figure out where should i upload my php files.

I have created a new folder inside the public_html folder as fortnox_invoicing and have copied all the code (PHP/HTML/JS) files in that folder.

But when i try to browse the php files it doesn't work instead i get "ops, this page does not exist" message.

```
http://example.com/fortnox_invoicing/index.php
```

Following is how the public_html directory looks like for now:

[image]

Comment: just remove these files and extract your project here.

Comment: That should work. How are you trying to access?

Comment: http://example.com/fortnox_invoicing/index.php

Comment: i dont know exact but i dont thing you can directly access sub folders.because example.com wiil fetch index page and for your directory these should be some link to show inner index.php.

Comment: if fortnox is your project then you need to keep all files of that folder to the outer folder where you kept fortnox folder.

Comment: Didn't work. Why can't i access sub folders ? There is no index.html or .htaccess file that can block or redirect access to subfolders.

Comment: Are you absolutely, 100% sure there is indeed a file `index.php` inside the `fortnox_invoicing` directory?

Answer (score 0):

You can upload your PHP files in public_html if you want to browse your website like:

http://example.com

You can also upload PHP files in subfolder if you wish to browse it like

http://example.com/subfolder

If you are receiving error 404 while browsing subfolder, locate .htaccess file and check if there is any rules that are restricting index.php to load and causing 404 page. If .htaccess file is hidden, you'll have to enable the show hidden file in while opening cPanel File Manager. Try renaming .htaccess file and load your website again. Also make sure that root folder contains index page and it is listed as default page in .htaccess file.

Answer (score -1):

You see this page because your website doesn't have "index.php" or "index.html" file in public_html folder. 
for example

**-public_html**

```
    -index.php
    **-subfolder**
         -aboutus.php
         -contact.php
         -service.php
         **-subfolder**
              -thankyou.php
```

Most service providers use the above hierarchy.